# Combining Multiple sheets from one work book into a single sheet on another work book with a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am just attempting this to help speed up cost comparisons, except my programming skills are laughable at this point. This is what I have so far...

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Last cell in column
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("Asphalt")
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1
End With

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)

'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile

'Set selectedworkbook
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

'Select cells to copy
wb2.Worksheets("Asphalt").Range("J3:R3").Copy

'Go back to original workbook you want to paste into
wb.Activate

'Paste starting at the last empty row
wb.Worksheets("Asphalt").Range("C" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Close and save the workbook you copied from
wb2.Save
wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Now first thing I can't seem to open another .xls workbook for whatever reason. Secondly I get a message saying my subscript is out of range.

Ultimately what I want to happen is to hit a button, open the work book I want to have as my initial costs and it will populate not only pricing but also line items and quantities. Then hit another button to open another workbook and import the costs from that workbook but only if the line items match.

Now I know this is a tall tall order and I will continue on my trek to get my goal of having this all powerful spreadsheet, but I would greatly appreciate any and all help that I can get.

Here is a picture of roughly what I would like the final project to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbyPq.jpg just minus manually inputting all the numbers in like a caveman ;)

Comment: `Dim vFile As Variant` means this has nothing at all to do with VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

Remove the part that says, including the quotation marks "Excel-files,*.xlsx" to allow it to open all file types.  The code should be

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)

As for subscript out of range that could be for a variety of reasons...so you would need to expand more on which part of the code is getting the subscript error.

Hope this helps

H